# How to upload data from Excel file to Sql Server using BizTalk

Tags: c#, sql-server, biztalk

I wanted to upload data from an Excel file (which will be located at some specified folder) to SQL Server using BizTalk.

I am using Visual Studio 2010,.NET V4 and SQL Server 2008.
Can anyone please provide me detailed steps of how to achieve this or any existing discussion/forum link for the same.

Thanks,
Mayur Jadhav

Answer (score 3):

Mayur, Excel sheets are basically binary files, you need a **custom pipeline component** for processing this excel file. I'm pasting a link *[here](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/matt/archive/2007/06/15/test.aspx)* that will help you out to carry out the desired task.

There is another article uploaded *[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37286/Excel-Reading-Custom-Pipeline-for-BizTalk-Server)* in the *code project* that aims to discuss how to read an Excel file from a pipeline in BizTalk. A custom pipeline need to be developed to read Excel files. Excel file will be read by taking the file adapter and the pipeline will process it. A custom pipeline component is nothing more than a simple .NET DLL that implements a class with some predefined interfaces. This interface represents the layer between a .NET program and the BizTalk Server.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: The output from the custom pipeline component that reads the Excel file will be an Xml message. This message will then be used to insert data into your SQL Database via the WCF SQL Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create flat file schema 
[how to create flat file schema in biztalk](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13706/Creating-Flat-File-schemas-using-the-BizTalk-Serve)

than you need to insert the data in to the DB i would use a store prudence that will insert the data into the db and than use the **LOB adapter** in order to cunsume it inside biztalk orchestration [LOB Adapter](http://seroter.wordpress.com/biztalk-and-wcf-part-vii-about-the-biztalk-adapter-pack/)

Comment: @MlkCode - I am still not able to read the MS Excel file using the flat file schema. Is there any other way I can read the Excel file and upload the data to SQL Server ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to process Excel files..
If you can control then save the Excel Files as XML and process them, otherwise looks for excel adapter for Biztalk. [For example](http://www.fpoint.com/biztalk/default.aspx)

You will then just have to work with mappings and port files. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577834%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) should help you.